# Motion in Spaces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

How does a shuttle move in the space as, the whole mechanism of a rocket is based on 3rd law of newton but, we can not apply 3rd law of newton in space because there is no reactive force in space?